# Oracle SQL Date type difference between versions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have faced the hemorrhoids using this:

Datamart D has a field AS_OF_DATE as DATE

My table T has a field AS_OF_DATE as DATE

If I try

```
where D.AS_OF_DATE = T.AS_OF_DATE
```

I have no rows.

If I do

```
where to_date(D.AS_OF_DATE) = to_date(T.AS_OF_DATE)
```

I have rows.

Why so?

Thanx in advance

My amateur's suggestions: datamart was Oracle v10, but...

Comment: What are the exact datatypes of the two tables? I doubt that they have the same definiton

Answer (score 1):

Never call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`

In order to see the difference try

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(D.AS_OF_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
   TO_CHAR(T.AS_OF_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM T
   CROSS JOIN D
```

then you should see the difference immediately.

Most likely you are looking for

```
WHERE TRUNC(D.AS_OF_DATE) = TRUNC(T.AS_OF_DATE)
```

A `DATE` value in Oracle always has also the time part, however it does not mean the time part is shown in default display format. Check default format with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
FROM DUAL;
```

When you run `TO_DATE()` on a `DATE` value, then Oracle make an implicit cast to string and then back to DATE again, i.e.

```
TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(D.AS_OF_DATE, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')),  SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT') )
```

It works if your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `dd.mm.yyyy` for example. However, if the default format includes the time then the condition will not return any row either.